# Convert BLOB to PDF

Tags: java, blob

I have a BLOB file which I have got from the DB team. I know that its a PDF document (I opened using Notepad++ and I could see the file name) and I need to convert the same using java. I have checked for few examples and I couldn't find any example where the BLOB file itself is taken as an input instead of taking directly from the DB (Resultset). Can anyone please give some pointers as to how I can accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

I have tried below,

```
File file = new File("C:/Users/User1/Desktop/0LK54E33K1477e2MCEU25JV0G8MG418S007N45JU.BLOB0");

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        //System.out.println(file.exists() + "!!");
        //InputStream in = resource.openStream();
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        try {
            for (int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(buf)) != -1;) {
                bos.write(buf, 0, readNum); //no doubt here is 0
                //Writes len bytes from the specified byte array starting at offset off to this byte array output stream.
                System.out.println("read " + readNum + " bytes,");
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            //Logger.getLogger(genJpeg.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();

        //below is the different part
        File someFile = new File("C:/Users/User1/Desktop/Test.pdf");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(someFile);
        fos.write(bytes);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
```

Comment: Why don't you just rename the file to `test.pdf`?

Comment: It is not about the file name, its getting stored in that path I have given. The thing is I am not able to open the PDF document. If I edit the PDF with Notepad++, I get the same result as the BLOB file. Will I get a different result if I just give Test.pdf?

Comment: You can't "edit" a PDF file with Notepad++. If you want to check if your code that copies the file works correctly you should compare the old and the new file using some kind of binary file compare. Btw: it's not necessary to first copy the whole file into a byte array in order to copy it. You might want to check [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) which already contains tested methods to copy files instead of re-inventing the wheel

Comment: file extensions are only there for some application associations. If the content of your stored (blob) file on your desktop is in the PDF format, you just need to rename the file's extension to `.pdf` in order to be able to open it with a pdf viewer in a simple way.

Comment: Thanks for the details. But here I don't want to just copy byte by byte. I want to convert the file to a PDF document. The end result should be that the BLOB file which is saved locally should be converted to a PDF document. Please let me know if there is any other way. Thanks again!

Comment: It is probable you don't need any conversion, i.e. your blob is already PDF file.

Comment: But I am not able to open the file even after renaming as .pdf. Not sure if there is any tool to open these types of files.

Comment: "I have a BLOB file which I have got from the DB team" - Ask the DB team what the format of that BLOB is! There may be a PDF stream contained somewhere inside, but it may have some special encoding or non-pdf (meta-)data in it which makes it not a valid PDF document.